# Empty Response Description and bad access-control-allow-methods in Swagger UI (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.5.1 +)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-5.0

After migration  from asp.core 2.2  to asp.core (3.1 -5.0)  and upgrading nuget Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to 5.5.1 or higher there is no Error Description  and allowed methods  look like 1 string in swagger UI.
Every thinks seems to work fine but this UI bug is annoying

**Code:**

```
//ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "COKP", Version = "v1",Description= "COKP API" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {

                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Wpisz token w postaci: Bearer .....",
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
            {
                    { new OpenApiSecurityScheme(){
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference{
                        Id = "Bearer",
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme }
                    }
                    ,new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });

//Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IMapper mapper)
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "COKP API");
        });
```

Before
[image: Before]
Now
[image]